# How to fix theorems with the same number?

Tags: theorems, newtheorem

First, I am sorry for my LaTeX file being in Portuguese.

I defined two theorems:

```
\newtheorem{axiomaconjuntovazio}{Axioma}
\newtheorem{axiomaigualdade}{Axioma}
```

Then I used them:

```
\subsection{Conjunto vazio}

A existência dum conjunto vazio é garantida por um axioma:

\begin{axiomaconjuntovazio}[Conjunto Vazio]
\cite{settheoryaxioms} Existe um conjunto que
não possui nenhum elemento:

\begin{center}
$\exists{x}\neg{\exists{y}}(y\in{x})$
\end{center}
\end{axiomaconjuntovazio}

\begin{sloppypar}

Sabendo de sua existência, é natural questionar se há mais de
um conjunto vazio, já que se define equalidade pelo conteúdo
dum conjunto e o conjunto vazio não possui nenhum elemento.
Para isso, é necessário saber o que é igualdade:

\begin{axiomaigualdade} [Igualdade]
\cite{settheoryaxioms} Um conjunto é igual a um outro conjunto apenas se possuírem os mesmos elementos:

\begin{center}
$\forall{x}\forall{y}(\forall{z}(z\in{x}\Longleftrightarrow{z\in{y}})\Longleftrightarrow{x=y})$.
\end{center}
\end{axiomaigualdade}
```

But the PDF generated by Overleaf gives the same number for both of them:

[image: Image with two different theorems with the same number]

So I ask: how can I fix it?

If the text in Portuguese makes it harder, I can translate it; just comment it. And, if needed, here's the whole file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\title{Prova do Teorema 2.6}
\author{G.S.S.}
\date{06/11/2020}

% Axiomas:
\newtheorem{axiomaconjuntovazio}{Axioma}
\newtheorem{axiomaigualdade}{Axioma}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% IIntrodução
\section{Introdução}
\begin{sloppypar}

Neste documento, se provará o Teorema 2.6, do
livro \mbox{\textit{Axioms and Set Theory}}\cite{settheorybook}
(p. 16). Esse teorema diz que o conjunto  vazio
\mbox{($\emptyset$)},
conjunto que não possui elementos, é um subconjunto de qualquer
conjunto, incluindo do próprio conjunto vazio, i.e.,
\mbox{$\forall{x}(\emptyset\subseteq{x})$}.

Motivou-se prová-la por um desafio do autor, um 
recém-estudante de teoria dos conjuntos, a si. Então, este 
texto tem unicamente o objetivo de provar idem dum modo
exageradamente formal para a diverção do autor --- talvez
sadismo.

\end{sloppypar}
\section{Definições}

As definições lógicas e o sistema derivativo lógico usados são
do livro \textit{Forall x: Calgary}\cite{logicbook}.

\subsection{Conjunto vazio}

A existência dum conjunto vazio é garantida por um axioma:

\begin{axiomaconjuntovazio}[Conjunto Vazio]
\cite{settheoryaxioms} Existe um conjunto que
não possui nenhum elemento:

\begin{center}
$\exists{x}\neg{\exists{y}}(y\in{x})$
\end{center}
\end{axiomaconjuntovazio}

\begin{sloppypar}

Sabendo de sua existência, é natural questionar se há mais de
um conjunto vazio, já que se define equalidade pelo conteúdo
dum conjunto e o conjunto vazio não possui nenhum elemento.
Para isso, é necessário saber o que é igualdade:

\begin{axiomaigualdade} [Igualdade]
\cite{settheoryaxioms} Um conjunto é igual a um outro conjunto apenas se possuírem os mesmos elementos:

\begin{center}
$\forall{x}\forall{y}(\forall{z}(z\in{x}\Longleftrightarrow{z\in{y}})\Longleftrightarrow{x=y})$.
\end{center}
\end{axiomaigualdade}

Reestruturou-se a pergunta para ``existe um conjunto sem
elementos, $x$, e existe um conjunto sem elementos, $y$, sendo
$x$ e $y$ conjuntos diferentes?'', i.e.,
[$\exists{x}\exists{y}(\neg\exists{z}(z\in{x})\land\neg\exists{z}(z\in{y})\land{}x\neq{y})?$], porque se existirem dois
conjuntos vazios, há mais de um conjunto vazio e não se elimina
a possibilidade de haver três ou mais conjuntos vazios
diferentes. Esta definição formal auxiliou na prova da
existência ou inexistência de dois conjuntos vazios.

\end{sloppypar}

\begin{proof}
Assumindo $\exists{x}\exists{y}(\neg\exists{z}(z\in{x})\land\neg\exists{z}(z\in{y})\land{}x\neq{y})$, tem-se
$\exists{x}\exists{y}(\neg\exists{z}(z\in{x})\land\neg\exists{z}(z\in{y})\land{}x\neq{y})$

\end{proof}

% Bibliografia
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why doyou incorporate the optional argument in the name of the environment? Just use  `\newtheorem{axioma}{Axioma}`.

Comment: @Bernard, which optional argument? Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: The note between parentheses after Axioma. The way you do it defines two independent counters.

Comment: Unless you added these notes only to make visible these do not belong to the same series of theorems?

Comment: @Bernard, are you talking about "[Igualdade]"?

Comment: @Sigur, agora entendi, obrigado! Now I get it, thanks!

Comment: I voted this question to close, hence it solved by comment from `Bernard`

Comment: @Schilive: Yes  I was alluding to ‘[Igualdade]’ and ‘[Conjunto vazio]’.

Comment: @Bernard, they add a message between parenthesis.

Comment: @Bernard, and also thanks for the answer. Now I see that you answered my question in the first comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the OP responded in a comment, the answer was provided in an earlier comment,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(@Bernard's suggestion -- to use a single theorem-like environment called, say, `axioma` -- solves the OP's main query. I'm posting this answer mainly to give the OP some pointers on how he/she might attempt to improve the quality of the LaTeX code.)

In addition to using a single environment type for both axioms, you may want to take note of the fact that `\forall`, `\exists`, and `\land` are not macros that take arguments. To be sure, `\forall{x}` does compile, but the reason for this success is *not* that `\forall` is a macro that takes an argument. Instead, the reason for why it compiles is that TeX first processes `\forall` and then `{x}` (replacing it with `x`). Thus, `\forall{x}` is better written as `\forall x`. etc.

To create unnumbered displayed equations, please don't write `\begin{center} $ ... $ \end{center}`. Instead, just write `\[ ... \]`.

Don't leave blank lines before `\end{axioma}`, `\end{proof}`, and the ends of other theorem-like environments.

Finally, don't overuse `sloppypar` environments, and don't use `\mbox` unless you're absolutely sure that it's the right thing to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{amsthm}
% Axiomas:
\newtheorem{axioma}{Axioma}

\title{Prova do Teorema 2.6}
\author{G.S.S.}
\date{06/11/2020}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\section{Introdução}

Neste documento, se provará o Teorema 2.6, do livro \textit{Axioms and Set Theory} \cite[p.~16]{settheorybook}. Esse teorema diz que o conjunto vazio ($\emptyset$), conjunto que não possui elementos, é um subconjunto de qualquer conjunto, incluindo do próprio conjunto vazio, i.e., $\forall x (\emptyset\subseteq x)$.

Motivou-se prová-la por um desafio do autor, um  recém-estudante de teoria dos conjuntos, a si. Então, este  texto tem unicamente o objetivo de provar idem dum modo exageradamente formal para a diverção do autor --- talvez sadismo.


\section{Definições}

As definições lógicas e o sistema derivativo lógico usados são do livro \textit{Forall~x: Calgary} \cite{logicbook}.

\subsection{Conjunto vazio}

A existência dum conjunto vazio é garantida por um axioma:
\begin{axioma}[Conjunto Vazio, \cite{settheoryaxioms}]
Existe um conjunto que não possui nenhum elemento:
\[
\exists x\neg\exists y (y\in x )
\]
\end{axioma}

Sabendo de sua existência, é natural questionar se há mais de um conjunto vazio, já que se define equalidade pelo conteúdo dum conjunto e o conjunto vazio não possui nenhum elemento. Para isso, é necessário saber o que é igualdade:
\begin{axioma}[Igualdade, \cite{settheoryaxioms}]
 Um conjunto é igual a um outro conjunto apenas se possuírem os mesmos elementos:
\[
\forall x\forall y(\forall z(z\in x \Longleftrightarrow z\in y)\Longleftrightarrow x=y )\,.
\]
\end{axioma}

Reestruturou-se a pergunta para ``existe um conjunto sem elementos, $x$, e existe um conjunto sem elementos, $y$, sendo $x$ e $y$ conjuntos diferentes?'', i.e., [\,$\exists x \exists y (\neg\exists z (z\in x )\land\neg\exists z(z\in y)\land x\neq y )?$], porque se existirem dois conjuntos vazios, há mais de um conjunto vazio e não se elimina a possibilidade de haver três ou mais conjuntos vazios diferentes. Esta definição formal auxiliou na prova da existência ou inexistência de dois conjuntos vazios.

\begin{proof}
Assumindo $\exists x \exists y (\neg\exists z (z\in x)\land\neg\exists z (z\in y)\land x\neq y)$, tem-se $\exists x \exists y (\neg\exists z (z\in x )\land\neg\exists z (z\in y)\land x\neq y)$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done! I also suggest a reminder that no blank line should precede `\end{proof}`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks! I've added your suggestion to the list of dos and don'ts.

Comment: @egreg, thanks.